# Keras using theano backend despite keras.json specifying tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras is using theano as a backend despite the .keras/keras.json file specifying tensorflow.

```
(conda_env) [centos@ip ~]$ cat .keras/keras.json
{
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "image_data_format": "channels_first", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}

Python 2.7.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 28 2018, 18:42:13) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Using Theano backend.
```

I have tensorflow installed and can import it without a problem. Where is keras getting the command to use theano as a backend and how can I change it?

Comment: I recommend you not to use anaconda, they override the normal keras config files with their own, that is why you have this problem. if you use official keras from pip it should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with anaconda, which is using its own file to determine the backend. You'll need to edit that file, which should be located somewhere like `/home/user/anaconda/envs/my_env/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.sh`